# Is it possible in SQL to use WITH inside a WITH

Tags: sql, view

In SQL, is it possible to place a WITH inside a WITH?

Take the below query for example,

```
WITH Temp ([Description], [Amount], [OverdueBy])
AS 
(select Description, SUM(Amount) as Amount, (DATEDIFF(day,DueDate,GETDATE())) as OverdueBy  from brvAPAllInvoices 
Where PaidDate is null and APCo = 1 and Amount > 0 
Group By Description, DueDate, APRef

)

select * from Temp
```

I want to create a "virtual" temporary table based off the above query. Is it possible to use another WITH to contain it in?

Something along the lines of this:

```
WITH Temp2 ([Description], [Amount], [OverdueBy])
AS
(
WITH Temp ([Description], [Amount], [OverdueBy])
AS 
(select Description, SUM(Amount) as Amount, (DATEDIFF(day,DueDate,GETDATE())) as OverdueBy  from brvAPAllInvoices 
Where PaidDate is null and APCo = 1 and Amount > 0 
Group By Description, DueDate, APRef

)

select * from Temp)

select * from Temp2
```

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WITH'.
Msg 319, Level 15, State 1, Line 4
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 12
Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Comment: Make sure to tag with the *actual* RDBMS used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't define a CTE within a CTE, however you can define multiple CTE's and reference other CTE's in a single statement.

```
; with a as (
    select * from some_table
),
b as (
   select * 
   from another_table t
     inner join a ON (t.key = a.key)
)
select * 
from b
```

Answer (score 3):

Depending on your dbms, you can have multiple WITH statements, nested or not. (Illustrated with PostgreSQL.) [SQL Server doesn't allow nesting common table expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx). (Search for *CTE_query_definition*.)

**Nested**

```
with today as (
  with yesterday as (select current_date - interval '1' day as yesterday)
  select yesterday + interval '1' day as today from yesterday 
)
select cast(today as date) from today
```

```
today
--
2014-06-11
```

When you nest common table expressions, the nested CTE isn't visible outside its enclosing CTE.

```
with today as (
  with yesterday as (select current_date - interval '1' day as yesterday)
  select yesterday + interval '1' day as today from yesterday 
)
select * from yesterday
```

```
ERROR: relation "yesterday" does not exist
```

**Unnested**

```
with yesterday as (
  select current_date - interval '1' day as yesterday
), 
today as (
  select yesterday + interval '1' day as today from yesterday 
)
select cast(yesterday as date) as dates from yesterday
union all
select cast(today as date) from today
```

```
dates
--
2014-06-10
2014-06-11
```

When you use successive, unnested CTEs, the earlier ones are visible to the later ones, but not vice versa.

```
with today as (
  select yesterday + interval '1' day as today from yesterday 
),
yesterday as (
  select current_date - interval '1' day as yesterday
) 
select yesterday from yesterday
union all
select today from today
```

```
ERROR:  relation "yesterday" does not exist
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd typically do something like the following;

```
WITH Temp ([Description], [Amount], [OverdueBy])
AS 
(select Description, SUM(Amount) as Amount, (DATEDIFF(day,DueDate,GETDATE())) as OverdueBy  from brvAPAllInvoices 
Where PaidDate is null and APCo = 1 and Amount > 0 
Group By Description, DueDate, APRef
), Temp2 ([Description], [Amount], [OverdueBy]) AS 
(
    SELECT * FROM Temp
)
select * from Temp2
```

Althouth in your contrived example, there obviously isn't much use as both table structures are pretty much the same. I tend to think of CTEs more as named derived tables than temporary tables too....even though they are much more than just a derived table